# Why does this command keep popping up when I open my terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

It says "adds" or something. Is there any way to get rid of it?
Also im using UXTerm but it happens in all other terminal

Comment: Can you edit your question and mention which terminal you're using?

Comment: Im using UXterm but it happens in all terminals

Comment: Probably something in your `.profile` (or a similar file).

Comment: Could be in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Okay, I'll look.

Comment: Thanks Jos the problem is a line came uncommented and the first word was adds

Comment: Good, I will rewrite this as an answer then. Please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

In all probability, there is a line in `.bashrc` that the shell attempts to execute before opening the terminal, and that shouldn't be there.